# How to change font in the unit siunitx?

Tags: fonts, siunitx

How can I change the font in the package `siunitx` ?

I want to set this font: `\fontfamily{qag}`.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
    %46paper
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[main=english, slovak]{babel}
    \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}

    \textbf{\SI{17}{\mm}} 
    \SI{17}{\mm}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want it only for the unit or generally for your text?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that this is a good font for running text. But if you want.

```
  \documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
    %46paper
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[main=english, slovak]{babel}
    \usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{tgadventor}
    \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    \sisetup{detect-weight,detect-mode} %or mode=tex?
    \begin{document}
    Some Text abc mm
    \textbf{\SI{17}{\mm}}
    \SI{17}{\mm} 

    in math: $x=\SI{17}{\mm}$

    \end{document}
```

[image]